# How I can redirect all pages of a folder to a certain page, using htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess

I had a [gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/) folder. Then I have deleted it. However all pages under it are still shown as "unable to find" under Google Webmasters tools. I want to redirect all pages of that folder to a certain page. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will redirect all `http://host/directory/anypage.html` to `http://host/somepage.html`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^directory/.+\.html$ somepage.html
```

Comment: I have done it with RewriteRule gallery/ http://example.com/images.php [R=permanent,L] but the GET parameter passes to the "new" page.